# PhoneGap has very long loadtime for EmberJs + AlmondJS application

Tags: cordova, ember.js, requirejs, almond

I have an EmberJs Application that is optimised and concatenated with r.js into one file, as a part of cordova/Phonegap application, the app load very fast on ios simulators but takes about 13 sec to load on real device.

Does anybody know what it could be the problem ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you doing any other data references? Maybe loading images or rendering them?

Comment: actually no the index page doesn't have any images, the thing is its loading very fast on emulator !!!! but not on ipad when it should be otherwise i guess.

Comment: one morething the website load very fast even on the ios device safari browser